# how to start foreach from specific line php

Tags: php

I have a simple foreach to read file in PHP. I want to start reading from the third  line

how can I start reading the file from specific line for example line 3 with the foreach

this is the code

```
$files = file_get_contents('empdata.txt');
$files = explode("\r\n", $files); 

foreach ($files as $number => $ccdata ) {
    $ccdata = trim($ccdata );
    list($ccempid, $ccempname, $ccempsalary) = explode("|", $ccempdata);
}
```

I try to make the index number line.

```
$number=3;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `if ($number >= 3) { //do process }` - inside loop

Comment: use `$number >= 2` because `$number` start from 0

Comment: Why use foreach? Use `fseek()` ?

Comment: Use a `for()` loop, but start at the number you are after.  If you have to use `foreach()` you could use `array_slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "filename.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
echo $lines[3];
```

I hope it would help you out.

Comment: but i use file_get_contents to get the file content

Comment: it would work with the entire file, so please try with file() instead of file_get_contents()

Comment: If you want to do it with file_get_contents(), you could explode() with a new line like that:

$myFile = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
$linesArr = explode("\n", $myFile);
echo $linesArr[3];

Answer (score 0):

You just ask if key is bigger or equals to 2:

```
foreach ($files as $number => $ccdata ) {
     if ($number >= 2){
        $ccdata = trim($ccdata );
        list($ccempid, $ccempname, $ccempsalary) =             explode("|", $ccempdata);
     }
 }
```

Comment: this will not work when i have a thousand line in the file and i wanna it from for example 456 it will tack time

Answer (score 0):

Use a different type of loop:

```
$files = file_get_contents('empdata.txt');
$files = explode("\r\n", $files); 

for ($number = 2; $number < count($files); $number++) {
    $ccdata = $files[$number];
    $ccdata = trim($ccdata );
    list($ccempid, $ccempname, $ccempsalary) = explode("|", $ccempdata);
}
```

This works because **explode()** will key each element in the array starting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple
use [`continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

```
foreach ($files as $number => $ccdata ) {
   if ($number < 3) continue;

   $ccdata = trim($ccdata );
   list($ccempid, $ccempname, $ccempsalary) = explode("|", $ccempdata);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks for all of you brothers

i fix it with this code

```
$files = file_get_contents('empdata.txt');
$files = explode("\r\n", $files); 
$plusone=3;
foreach ($files as $number => $ccdata ) {
            if ($plusone >= 0) {
                $ccdata = $files[$plusone];
                $number = $plusone;
            } else {
                $ccdata = $files[$number];
            }
    $ccdata = trim($ccdata );
    list($ccempid, $ccempname, $ccempsalary) = explode("|", $ccempdata);
}
```